# How to increment a counter and return the value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that has a Key column and a Counter column. I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT counter=counter+1 FROM table WHERE key='mykey'
```

Basically, I need to increment the Counter column and return the new value. How can I do this in MySQL 5.5?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
update mytable set count=last_insert_id(counter+1) where key='mykey'
```

Then

```
select last_insert_id()
```

`last_insert_id()` can be passed an argument to 'set' it (and return that value), and calling it without an argument will return the value again. The internal state used by `last_insert_id()` is per-connection, which means that the same `update` statement issued on another connection will not affect the first.

Reference: [`last_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: This table will be very heavily used, what happens if another update happens before the select? Won't the value of last_insert_id be wrong?

Comment: The the answerer said: `last_insert_id()` is per connection. So what other connections do does not affect you. If **you** do any inserts/replaces then yes it will be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Would connection pooling affect this, or would the connection not be re-used until closed?

Comment: There does exist a small chance of race condition on the same connection if thread B does an `update` between thread A's `update` and `select`, but that would be a concurrency flaw in the app itself since the app needs to make the 2 operations atomic somehow, not the database.

Comment: Connection pooling just internally keeps a number of open connections and hands them out on `Open()`. As long as you use the same connection object for both statements, it'll be fine.

Comment: The app is NOT supposed to make the data atomic, that's the database' job. Transactions are made for this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html

Comment: When scaled with several app instances, second query can return some other ID, because someone else could have succeded inserting a new increment value, while between those two queries. This should be done in one query or with locking, like `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in PostgreSQL.