# Using a MySQL row as a shared counter but its incredibly slow

Tags: mysql

This code is used by multiple different servers so it's important that they never get a duplicate value. The "for update" statement fixed that but its too slow now. Please help me identify why this is so slow. We ran a test calling increment() 1000 times and it took 9 minutes.

```
@Component
public class Counter {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Counter.class);

    @Value("${cloud.aws.rds.host:redacted}")
    private String mysqlHost;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.rds.password.counter:redacted}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.rds.connection.pool.size:5}")
    private int connectionPoolSize;

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public enum Counters {A, B, C, D};

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
        bds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:3306/Counter", mysqlHost);
        bds.setUrl(url);
        bds.setUsername("counter");
        bds.setPassword(password);
        bds.setInitialSize(connectionPoolSize);
        dataSource = bds;

        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
            stmt.executeUpdate("create table if not exists Counters (CounterID int not null, Service char(20) not null, Counter int not null, primary key(CounterID))");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert ignore into Counters(CounterID, Service, Counter) values('1', 'A', '1')");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert ignore into Counters(CounterID, Service, Counter) values('2', 'B', '1')");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert ignore into Counters(CounterID, Service, Counter) values('3', 'C', '1')");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert ignore into Counters(CounterID, Service, Counter) values('4', 'D', '1')");
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to connect to database: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public int increment(Counters counter, int max) {

        int counterValue = 1;
        String select = "Select Counter from Counters where Service=? for update";
        String update = "update Counters set Counter=? where Service=?";
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select);
            PreparedStatement updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(update)) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            selectStatement.setString(1, counter.name());
            try(ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if(rs.next()) {
                    counterValue = rs.getInt("Counter");
                }
            }
            if (counterValue >= max) {
                counterValue = 0;
            }
            updateStatement.setInt(1, counterValue + 1);
            updateStatement.setString(2, counter.name());
            updateStatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            logger.error("Failed Counter transactions: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return counterValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more details what you're trying to accomplish? It sort of feels like you're trying to code an auto_increment yourself

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing this guy is doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153657/how-to-increment-a-counter-and-return-the-value-in-mysql     I need to read the value of a column called Counter, which is used elsewhere as an increasing unique ID, then update it.

Comment: Why not make a second table that you could call counter_use that would have an auto_increment as its primary key. Then, when you need to, you insert into that table and use last_insert_id() to get a guaranteed unique value every time?

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try that..